# What's the minimum value?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, trigonometry

What's the maximum and the minimum value of $x$?

$$\frac{(\sqrt{100-x^2}+\sqrt{99+x^2})}{40} = \cos \frac{\pi}{x^2-2|x|+4}$$

I've done all what I could do but I failed. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: From $\sqrt{100-x^2}$ any solutions must be in the range $-10\le x\le10$.  Also notice that all expressions are even, so if $x_M$ is the maximum, then $-x_M$ is the minimum.

Comment: There are no real values for $x$ for which $\frac{(\sqrt{100-x^2}+\sqrt{99+x^2})}{40} = \cos \frac{\pi}{x^2-2|x|+4}$ holds true.

Comment: @Maazul, please establish your point

Comment: @Ewin, **hint** compare both sides to $1 \over 2$.

Comment: @Ewin : what are you asking?  The two sides of your equation are different at least for $x=0$.  Are you asking for the minimum and maximum values of $x$ that solve the equation?

Comment: For the minimum and maximum values of $x$ which satisfy $\frac{(\sqrt{100-x^2}+\sqrt{99+x^2})}{40} = \cos \frac{\pi}{x^2-2|x|+4}$, shouldn't there first exist some $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{(\sqrt{100-x^2}+\sqrt{99+x^2})}{40} = \cos \frac{\pi}{x^2-2|x|+4}$ is satisfied? For example, maximum value of $x$ which satisfies $x^2=4$ is $2$. Or is it that only the domain of $x$ is meant by the question?

Comment: "what are you asking?" I'm asking what's the minimum and the maximum of the of x can attain.

Answer (score 2):

Show that lhs attains it s minimum at $x=\pm 1/\sqrt{2}$ and this maximum equals $\frac{1}{20}\sqrt{\frac{199}{2}}$ which is less than $\frac{1}{2}$. Now consider rhs. Note that argument of cosine is always between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{3}$, hence the whole cosine is between $\frac{1}{2}$ and $1$. In other words rhs of the equation if not less than $\frac{1}{2}$.

Since lhs is strictly less than $\frac{1}{2}$ and rhs is not less than $\frac{1}{2}$ there is no real soltions of the original equation.

Comment: $(1/20)\sqrt{199/2}$ is *less* than $1/2$.

Comment: @RickDecker fixed